# Does Excel's Worksheet Comparison Operator Give Inconsistent Results?

Tags: excel, floating-point, comparison, excel-formula, vba

Consider the following. Place `=400000000000000/3` in a cell, say "A1". Excel displays `133333333333333.0000`. The precision is zero digits to the right of the decimal point because, apparently, Excel's floating point precision is no more than 15 digits. Now place the following formula in a cell:

```
=A1=ROUND(A1,0)
```

The formula produces `True` since there are no digits to the right of the decimal point ... or are there? Open the VBA editor, right click on your Workbook in the Projects pane and insert a VBA module. Define the following UDF:

```
Function Equals(dblOne As Double, dblTwo As Double) As Boolean
    Equals = dblOne = dblTwo
End Function
```

Now go back to your Worksheet and place the following formula in a cell:

```
=Equals(A1,ROUND(A1,0))
```

The result is now `False`. Why?

Comment: What if you change it to `Decimal` instead ?

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur, I'm not sure how I would. Decimal is only a subtype of Variant, you cannot say `X As Decimal` in a VBA Function header.

Comment: Thomas : Its because of difference. Add a `msgbox dblTwo - dblOne`

Comment: Please explain downvote

Comment: Kindly 'close' the questions by marking correct answers. This is what people here like when helping others. It will help ppl with same problem to identify the correct solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Excel's 15 apparent decimal digits of precision are the object of an entire section of William Kahan's [essay](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Mindless.pdf) “How Futile are Mindless Assessments of Roundoff in Floating-Point Computation ?”:

> What’s so special about 15 sig. dec.? Displaying at most 15 sig. dec.,
>   as Excel does, ensures that a number entered with at most 15 sig.
>   dec., converted to binary floating-point rounded correctly to 53 sig.
>   bits (which is what Excel’s arithmetic carries), and then displayed
>   converted back to decimal floating-point rounded correctly to at least
>   as many sig. dec. as were entered but no more than 15, will always
>   display exactly the same number as was entered. The decision to make
>   Excel’s arithmetic seem to be Decimal instead of Binary restricted
>   Excel’s display to at most 15 sig. dec., thus hiding the deception
>   well enough to reduce greatly the number of calls upon Excel’s
>   technical help-desk. When symptoms of the deception are perceived they
>   are routinely misdiagnosed; e.g., see David Einstein’s column on p. E2
>   of the San Francisco Chronicle for 16 and 30 May 2005.

The section concludes with:

> This is no place to list all the corrections Excel needs. It was cited
>   here only to exemplify Errors Designed Not To Be Found.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the below code msgbox gives the difference in two values. Hence it returns false.

```
   Function Equals(dblOne As Double, dblTwo As Double) As Boolean
        MsgBox dblOne - dblTwo
        Equals = dblOne = dblTwo
    End Function
```

Below code will return true

```
Function Equals(dblOne As Double, dblTwo As Double) As Boolean
    Equals = Round(dblOne, 0) = dblTwo
End Function
```

Comment: Your now rounding both sides. Of course it will return true. The question is why the same two numbers are equal in one comparison but not equal in the other.